# Twig recursive menu

Tags: loops, frameworks, twig, slim

I have this table

```
id | Type_number | Number
1    fax           01234
2    mobile        789-123
3    phone         000-555
4    fax           022354
5    phone         000-687
```

I need to group by type and list the number in group by type

**Example**

```
FAX
01234
022354

mobile
789-123

phone
000-555
000-687
```

if i have a this code :

```
<div class="colour_container">
{% for rec in list_number if rec.type == "fax" %}
{{ rec.type_number }}    {{ rec.number }}
{% endfor %}
</div>
    <div class="colour_container">
{% for rec in list_number if rec.type == "phone" %}
{{ rec.type_number }}    {{ rec.number }}
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

The cycle "for" function only for the first loop "fax" in the second no.
why ?

Comment: Can you try dumping your `rec` array in PHP, before you pass it into the template?  You can use `print_r($rec)` to output the raw contents of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me. Just try this example.

**index.php**

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Slim\Slim(array(
    'view' => new \Slim\Views\Twig()
));

$view = $app->view();

$view->parserExtensions = array(
    new \Slim\Views\TwigExtension()
);

$view->parserOptions = array(
    'debug' => true
);

$menu = array(
    array(
        "id" => 1,
        "type" => "fax",
        "number" => "01234"
    ),
    array(
        "id" => 2,
        "type" => "mobile",
        "number" => "789-123"
    ),
    array(
        "id" => 3,
        "type" => "phone",
        "number" => "000-555"
    ),
    array(
        "id" => 4,
        "type" => "fax",
        "number" => "022354"
    ),
    array(
        "id" => 5,
        "type" => "phone",
        "number" => "000-687"
    )
);

$app->get('/', function () use($app, $menu) {
    $app->render('index.twig', array(
        'list_number' => $menu,
        'types' => array("fax", "mobile", "phone")
    ));
});

$app->run();
```

**index.twig**

```
<div class="colour_container">
    {% for type in types %}
        {% set printed = false %}
        {{ type }}
        <br/>
        {% for rec in list_number if rec.type == type %}
            {{ rec.number }}<br/>
        {% endfor %}
        <br/>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: It's function only for first loop. (first type)

Comment: @Simsar78 I've just tried it and it works correctly.

Comment: You have two versione 2? i use version 1.1 because i don't have php 7

Comment: @Simsar78 I was using PHP 5.6 and Twig 1.* in this example. Maybe it could be easier to create another question about the problem you are facing, including the versions of the packages you're using and the environment.